# не могу решить задачу check_query()

Tags: python

Анфиса научилась отличать своё имя от других. Теперь надо научить её извлекать суть запроса.
Перепишите функцию `check_query()` так, чтобы при любом запросе она «отрезала» от строки имя и возвращала только запрос, без имени.

Например, если Анфисе пришёл запрос «Толя, что это за ерунда?» — функция `check_query()` должна вернуть строку 'что это за ерунда?'.

```
def check_query(query):
    
# Дальше следует код, вызывающий вашу функцию; не изменяйте его:
queries = [
    'Анфиса, сколько у меня друзей?',
    'Андрей, ну где ты был?',
    'Андрей, ну обними меня скорей!',
    'Анфиса, кто все мои друзья?'
]

for q in queries:
    result = check_query(q)
    print(q, '—', result)
```

подсказка: Верните из функции `check_query()` второй элемент списка `elements`

Comment: ваши попытки ?.

Comment: мои попытки это сплошной ступор, предыдущие 2 задачи я решил без проблем. с этой я даже не пойму с чего начать ....

Comment: может вам это поможет https://pythonru.com/osnovy/stroki-python обратите внимание на split()

Answer (score 0):

Если им'я в начале:

```
queries = [
    'Анфиса, сколько у меня друзей?',
    'Андрей, ну где ты был?',
    'Андрей, ну обними меня скорей!',
    'Анфиса, кто все мои друзья?'
]
def check_query(text):
  c=0
  for x in text:
    if x == " ": return(text[c+1:])
    c+=1
for q in queries:
  result=check_query(q)
  print(q, '—', result)
```

Comment: Зачем же так сложно, если есть, например, `find`, который делает тоже самое, что ваш цикл. Не говоря уже про `split`

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_query(query):
    elements = query.split(', ')
    return (elements[-1])
     
        
        
# Напишите код функции


# Дальше следует код, вызывающий вашу функцию; не изменяйте его:
queries = [
    'Анфиса, сколько у меня друзей?',
    'Андрей, ну где ты был?',
    'Андрей, ну обними меня скорей!',
    'Анфиса, кто все мои друзья?'
]

for q in queries:
    result = check_query(q)
    print(q, '—', result)
```

Comment: На этих примерах работать будет, но возникнет проблема, если дальше в строке ещё будет запятая и пробел

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_query(query):
   elements  = query.split (', ')
   return elements [1]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Если что то не получается, попробуйте прочитать тему заново, на задачи по курсу, все ответы имеются в тех же темах, где и задачи.

```
def check_query(query):
elements  = query.split(', ')
    if 'Анфиса' in elements:
        return 'запрос к Анфисе'
    else:
        return 'запрос к кому-то ещё'
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: У вас явно что-то не то с отступами.